LibreOffice Calc - Check if event date is in period of time and return event attribute
In spreadsheet like this:




A
B
C
D
E




1
Shift start
Shift end


Sum of event durations on that shift (min)


2
01.03.2024 15:35
02.03.2024 08:00


105


3
13.03.2024 15:35
14.03.2024 08:00


120


4
28.03.2024 15:35
29.03.2024 08:00


0


5
31.03.2024 08:00
01.04.2024 08:00


95


6


Event date
Event duration (min)



7


01.03.2024 21:00
20



8


01.03.2024 21:45
85



9


07.03.2024 14:15
70



10


13.03.2024 20:00
120



11


31.03.2024 23:45
85



12


01.04.2024 05:45
10




What's the formula to get values in cells E2:E5? Can I do this without macros and LibreOffice Basic coding?
Assumptions:

A, B, C and D columns' data changes each month both in value and quantity, but let's assume there can't be more than 100 events and shifts.
Not all events happen during shifts.

Formula I wanna get in words (read without brackets to make it more clear)

If any event date (cell value from range C7:C12) is between shift start and end dates (cells' values from range A2:B5), return event duration (other cell value from range D7:D12) and add it to E1, Sum of event durations (existing value in formula's cell). And so on for next cells in E column.

Formula I wanna get typed in "codish" language:
for each cell in C7:C12:
    for each row in rows(2:5):
        if (cell >= A+row and cell < B+row):
            E+row += D+cell.rowNumber


I tried =SUMPRODUCT(((D8>=$B$3:$B$6)*(D8<$C$3:$C$6))>0) found somewhere on this forum to check if event happens on shift (between two dates) and it returns boolean value 1 or 0. I need it to do a bit more and return at least any other data like row number or cell number.
Also tried with =MATCH and =IF formulas, searched the formulas library, but I can't find any formula which would include cell ranges (matrixes, lists) in that many parts.
It's way easier to dived more complicated formulas into few cells and small formulas but such "nested loops" would take a variable number of tons of cells to iterate over each especially when I have more shifts and events than shown in the example.
For example I can easily check =IF(AND(D8>=B3;D8<C3);E8;0), but it doesn't supply iteration and cell ranges/matrixes
I noticed it's way easier to work with date values if they are converted to numbers, esp. with dates around ends of months/years


After few days of tries and errors I managed to reach correct formula. I'm leaving the answer here as I think that's a formula that's needed frequently in many calculations.
To leave some tags for easier finding: For each value in column C check if it's between any value pair from columns A and B, same row, and if it matches, return value from column D that's paired with value from  column C in the same row.




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
Shift start
Shift end


Sum of event durations on that shift (min)




2
1.03.2024
2.03.2024


105
105
2


3
13.03.2024
14.03.2024


120
120
3


4
28.03.2024
29.03.2024


0
0
4


5
31.03.2024
1.04.2024


95
95
5


6


Event date
Event duration (min)

SUMIF($E$7:$E$12; ADDRESS(G2;6); $D$7:$D$12)



7


1.03.2024
20
$F$2




8


1.03.2024
85
$F$2




9


7.03.2024
70





10


13.03.2024
120
$F$3




11


31.03.2024
85
$F$5




12


1.04.2024
10
$F$5









IFNA(ADDRESS(1+MATCH(1; (C7>$A$2:$A$5)*(C7<$B$2:$B$5); 0);6);"")





So in E7 the formula is as written in E13: =IFNA(ADDRESS(1+MATCH(1; (C7>$A$2:$A$5)*(C7<$B$2:$B$5); 0);6);""
The formula returns cell number with row number of the matching shift and column name of our will.
To explain, match formula checks row by row if both conditions are true and returns true if it finds first pair that fulfil conditions. The address formula returns cell address, the number 1+match gives correct offset as there is a title in the row one, and the number 6 stands for column number that's not really important, but is helpful for next formula conditioning.
And in F2 there is formula as wriiten in F6: =SUMIF($E$7:$E$12; ADDRESS(G2;6); $D$7:$D$12)
It checks returned values from prievous formula if the equals our condition which is address formula and returns durations from corresponding row and column.
Values in column G are a helper values for easier expanding formula across whole F column
